# Charset database

Tags: character-encoding, collation

Im having the following charset problem.

1. Through a form user add name info (chars like åäö is common) - so far no problem
2. Mysqli adds the name to database - so far no problem
3. In the database chars like åäö shows as eg Ã¶ - problem
4. When grabing the name info containing the Ã¶ and presenting them on the page they shows up right, like åäö.

But, I dont think it looks nice to have chars like Ã¶ in the database.

Where is my charset problem? My collation of the database is utf8_swedish_ci, type MyISAM.

EDIT, my code:

```
try {               
                    // Create DB object
                    $db = Db::factory($this->type, $this->creds);

                    // Create a prepared statement
                    $sql = new Sql($db, 'user');
                   // This doesnt work  $sql->("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

                    $sql->insert(array('firstname' => '?', 'surname' => '?', 'email' => '?', 'password' => '?'));

                    // Prepare the statement, bind the parameters and execute
                    $db->adapter()->prepare($sql);
                    $db->adapter()->bindParams(array('firstname' => $post['firstname'], 'surname' => $post['surname'],
                                                    'email' => $post['email'], 'password' => $encryptedPassword));
                    $db->adapter()->execute();

                    $this->sendUserData($post['email'], $password);

                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                }
```

Comment: So, you need to make your webpages UTF-8 too.. what charset are they in?

Comment: Yes, the document is formated in Unicode (UTF-8) and I have this in my <head> -tag: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the connection's collation to UTF-8, which is iso-8859-1 by default. Try

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Then next problem comes up. Im using a Framework (www.popphp.org) which using prepared statement, so Im not sure how to set charset to it. Have added my code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The framework doesn't allow passing options to PDO so you have to do something like this:

```
$db = Db::factory($this->type, $this->creds);
$db->adapter()->exec("SET names 'UTF8'");
```